# FileAlterationListenerAdaptor stops firing after several hours

Tags: java, apache-commons-io

On a linux box, I have a process that monitors a mounted file system that points to a windows shared folder. Everything works fine for several hours, but at some point over night, the monitoring stops. The app is still running, and the mount point is still active. No exceptions are thrown from the app when files are added/updated - they're just completely missed.
To fix, I've added a scheduled task in my application to restart my listeners every 4 hours. This has run successfully for several days with no loss of monitoring.
Has anyone experienced similar issues?
JDK 8, commons v2.6
fstab:
//path/to/shard/folder /mnt/MOUNT cifs credentials=/home/me/credentials.txt,username=me,uid=1001,gid=1001,rw,auto 0 0
Centos7

Thoughts?

Comment: I don't think this area has changed that much but version 2.6 is pretty old. Have you tried updating?

Comment: Updated this morning and identified the same issue. I guess its time to build out a full test where I can duplicate at will. Thanks.

Comment: We have the same problem. Are there any updates?